# Can't set cookie in yii2

Tags: cookies, yii2

When i try to read the cookie getting null.

CODE:

```
$date = new \DateTime();
Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => $this->post_id,
    'value' => $date,
    'expire' => time() + 3600*12,
    'path' => '/post/view/?id=' . $this->post_id,
    'domain' => '.eshop.loc',
])); 

$this->response['cookie'] = Yii::$app->request->cookies->getValue($this->post_id);
```

Tell me please where is the problem?

Comment: what is `$this->response[]` where have you declared it

Comment: added it to the AJAX answer

Answer (score 0):

You have provided invalid cookie save path remove the path variable

```
'path' => '/post/view/?id=' . $this->post_id,
```

How is it going to save it on this path it needs a physical location. by default it is `/` use it with the default or provide a valid path. with an invalid path it wont save cookie and wont retrieve it. Try getting things running with minimal setup first and then add more things gradually so that if some wrong configuration is given it is spotted at the right time, remove the `path` and `domain` too and then try to save and retrieve.

Comment: I left only "name" and  "value", but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to be able to send and read a cookie under the same request.

Try getting it, if it is null, set it and it will be available in the following request.

Comment: I did as you indicated, but it also does not work. But if I use php functions then everything works: setcookie ($ this-> post_id, 'value of cookie');

Comment: Can you try with path `/` and a simple value? DateTime has no `__toString() ` method and cookies can only store strings.

Comment: left only: 'name' => $this->post_id,
 'value' => 'value of cookie', also don't work

Comment: Do you have a cookieValidationKey in app config - components - request? Although that would have thrown an error.

Comment: Update your code with what you did (setting if null, reading if exists).